# PHP echo not showing up in one computer?

Tags: php, echo

I have a php script that queries a MySQL database and populates a drop-down menu using the data received. Everything was working fine and suddenly, the echo "Custom" option doesn't show up for me. I asked someone else to check the same page, and it showed up for him. I tried changing browsers, and nothing. Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
echo '<div class="c_element" style="height: auto;"> 
    <select class="c_sel">';
        $c= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM C WHERE c_lo_id =".$sel_lo_id) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($c))
        {
            echo '<option value='.$row['c_id'].'>'.$row['c_name'].'</option>';              
        }

        echo '<option value="0">Custom </option>
    </select>';
```

Comment: Why `echo` anyway? Why not just use templating?

Comment: Doesn't look like you have any syntax errors, and I tested and have Custom showing up as an option. can you try adding something else to the echo?

Comment: He's probably messing with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if your values contain characters that break your html, like `'`, `>` or `<`. When outputting to html, you should always make sure that these are encoded correctly.

Apart from that this would also happen if there are spaces in your values as you don't quote the attribute value.

With both corrections:;

```
 echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['c_id']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['c_name']).'</option>';
                     ^ added as well                    ^
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. What I'm currently fetching from the DB is just some dummy data (Lorem ipsum sentences, actually). What's really strange is that it works in another computer, but not in mine.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that now.
Ok, tried it. Still doesn't show up. Thanks for pointing out the quotes, can't believe I missed them.

Comment: @Veris If this does not solve it (it should), you should post the html source code.